# is it ok to have persistent classes as fields in a DTO?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a class which models a data transfer object, I have an object attribute in it which is based of a persistent class. Is it good practice to do that? Here's the class in question:

```
    public class WorkRequest {

    private Long id;

    private String type;

    private Worker worker;

    private JobItem jobItem; // persistent class object

    private Set<WorkQuantity> quantities;

    public WorkRequest() {}
}
```

Comment: Some attributes in persistent object might be of lazy initialization,which  means they are  initialized (set)  only when they are first accessed ,so it may cause connection close exception

Comment: @neo, I intend to have those attributes loaded, some of them too have "@jsonIgnore", which means that their get method won't be called - thus I don't think the close exception will be thrown

Comment: Yep,you can define your class in this way,avoiding to create another `pojo`,just make sure you know everything about it that could cause this trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not *good* practice, because in general it is good to separate the domain model data from the data transported to other systems. Meaning if in the future you add some fields to JobItem class, you may accidentally also send them with your DTO to other systems causing data leaks or bugs.

However in many cases that concern does not matter much.